# How do I place a button on a custom view?

Tags: android

I need to use a custom view in order to show an animation. Right now I have a layout with a button, and when that button is pressed, the custom view is set and the animation starts inmediately. The problem is that the button should be on top of the custom view so the user can see the view before the animation starts.

I have searched and I think it can be done by using a FrameLayout, but I don't know how to implement a custom view inside a FrameLayout. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Make a Layout with the stuff you want inside the FrameLayout such as a LinearLayout, Relative, etc..

Inflate that Layout using a inflater and them place the layout on your FrameLayout

Or you can inflate your customView and add the view to it.

```
View myCustonView = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.mycustomview);

myCustomView.addView(myButton);
```

Comment: It doesn't work. This is what I did:                               View ExampleView = (View) inflater.inflate(ExampleView);
   ExampleView.addView(R.layout.frame);
   setContentView(new ExampleView(this));                                                  Both the inflater and the addview give me errors